# How to set a single header file as C++ compiler in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header-files, objective-c++, regexkitlite

There are some C++ files in my Objective-C project. In order to use STL in header files, I set the project setting to compile source as Objective-C++ in "Build Setting".

But now, I want to use *RegexKitLite* in my project. I found out RegexKitLite give a compilation error in the *Objective-C++* mode，but does compile correctly in the *Objective-C* mode or when determined automatically in "According to File Type" mode.

My questions is:

1. How to set a single header file to compile as C++? (I set the *File Type* as "C++ Header" in *Identity and Type*, but no effect is seen.).
2. How to use RegexKitLite from "Objective-C++"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header files are not a compilation unit (they are not compiled by themselves, but just included in other files), so setting the type does not have any influence on compilation.

If you include the header from some C++-compiled file, it will be compiled with C++ compiler.
Similarly, if you include the exactly the same header file from Objective-C file, it will be compiled with Objective-C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Headers are not specific by defaut.
.cpp use cpp compiler and .mm obj c.
So if you have an error it may be because you use a c++ that can not be compiled in objective c (but I don t think it is possible)
Better guess you use a header including obj c declarations in a C++ header.

separate your code to only include c++ compliant code in the cpp files

Comment: As I remember `.m` files are Objective-C, while `.mm` files are Objective-C++?

Comment: because i use stl::map to declare some type ,so i need include <map> in header file.

Comment: I don t think including map in an obj c ++ file is dangerous. maybe you use it in obj c (non c++) file?